# Why does the color not display in the textarea based on time condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, momentjs

I am trying to get my calendar blocks to change color depending on the current time.

I’ve made variables at different times (military time) and compared them with the current time in a conditional statement. For example in this condition, I displayed that `09:00` is less than the current time which is `20:00`. However, the color is not executed on the page when this condition is `true`.

```js
var dayTime = (moment().format('HH'))
var nine = '09';

console.log(nine);

var ten = '10';
var eleven = '11';
var twelve = '12';
var one = '13';
var two = '14';
var three = '15';
var four = '16';
var five = '17';

if (nine < dayTime) {
  $('#nineText').addclass('past');
}
```

```css
.past {
  background-color: #ff6961;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<div class="time-block">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">
      <p class='hour'>9AM</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
      <textarea id='nineText' class="form-control" type='text' placeholder='placeholder' rows="2.9"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <button class="input-group-addon saveBtn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I feel like I have the logic correct, but I know I am missing a step.

Comment: Your css class is not `present`.

Comment: The method is `addClass` (not `addclass`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is `addClass` not addclass, your class name is different from what you have mentioned in the question.

```js
var dayTime = new Date().getHours();
var nine = '09';
console.log(nine);
console.log("Current hours "  + dayTime);
var ten = '10';
var eleven = '11';
var twelve = '12';
var one = '13';
var two = '14';
var three = '15';
var four = '16';
var five = '17';





if (parseInt(nine) <= parseInt(dayTime)){
$('#nineText').addClass('present');
}
```

```css
.present {
background-color: #ff6961;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "time-block">
  <div class ="row">
      <div class="col-1">
          <p class='hour'>9AM</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-10">
          <textarea id ='nineText'  class="form-control"  type='text' placeholder= 'placeholder'  rows="2.9"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
          <button class="input-group-addon saveBtn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Save</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```